# Who is the man who fails to engineer dinner with Julia Montague?

Tags: character, bodyguard

In episode 2 of *Bodyguard* (the 2018 BBC drama), Home Secretary Julia Montague meets a man for dinner. It transpires that none of her other friends have been told to attend, even though she was expecting a group dinner. It appears that the man has engineered the dinner to be just for the two of them. Julia says that the situation feels 'weird', and leaves with her bodyguard DS Budd. The man left behind looks crestfallen.

Who is he, and what is he trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [**this article**](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/entertainment/tv/bodyguard-episode-2-whose-side-is-david-budd-on-really/ar-BBMwD3o) it's...**Rob MacDonald**

> Rob MacDonald is the special advisor to the Home Secretary

---

> There were hints last week that Montague was having an affair with adviser **Rob Macdonald** (Paul Ready). Now he duped her into dinner-a-deux by pretending they were meeting friends.

As for what he's trying to accomplish...it's probably too early to tell.

Comment: In Episode 5, DS Budd states that Julia 'rejected his advances', presumably referring to the abortive dinner.